# core file is not created when program crashes

Tags: linux

I have a test program that crashes and I am expecting it to create a core file. When it crashes, it outputs (core dumped), however a core file is not created.

This is running on an amazon ec2 suse server.

```
./crashtest
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

uname -a
Linux ip-172-31-6-104 4.4.21-90-default #1 SMP Fri Dec 9 09:49:02 UTC 2016     (fc1fe0e) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 3675
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 3675
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited


cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
|/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t %e


ls -l crashtest
    -rwxrwxrwx 1 ec2-user users 6728 May 23 10:49 crashtest
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question appears to be off-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help].  It may be better suited to the [Unix and Linux](//unix.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Briefly, it looks like that `core_pattern` directs the dump to an external program.  What that does with it will need to be found in the `systemd-coredump` documentation.

Comment: Can you share the contents in /var/lib/systemd/coredump